# Embedding OSGi framework: when does bundle resolution should be done?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix

**Objective**

I'm currently adapting an existing Java application, by transforming it into a plugin-based system. This is a Spring MVC-based web service which providers various services. I intend to make these services pluggable, provided by OSGi bundles. I already have all OSGi bundles providing those services, created with the `maven-bundle-plugin`.

**What I have done**

I decided to embed an OSGI framework (Apache Felix) into my application using the OSGi R4 API, by adding it as a Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

initializing it:

```
FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader
    .load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
config.put(FelixConstants.LOG_LEVEL_PROP, Integer.toString(Logger.LOG_DEBUG));
this.framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
this.framework.init();
this.context = framework.getBundleContext(); // keep ref to context
```

installing all bundles through the context:

```
context.installBundle(jarPath)
```

and starting the framework:

```
framework.start();
```

I then check the state of all bundles and all except the framework have a `INSTALLED` state. The framework bundle is `ACTIVE`.

Obviously the installed bundles were not resolved.

**Question**

When is Felix suppose to attempt to resolve bundles? From what I understood from the OSGi life-cycle, resolution would happen automatically. But I can't tell if Felix is even attempting to resolve the bundles. It does not print any log, even though I configured log level to DEBUG. It would be easy to debug my set up if I could see why a certain bundle is not able to resolve (i.e. can Felix tell me which packages are missing?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felix's behaviour is correct, because you have not started any of the bundles. If you do not start them, then there is no need to resolve them, and therefore they stay in the `INSTALLED` state.

In order for your application to actually do anything, you will need to start the bundles. You should do this *after* you have installed all of the bundles... that is, you should install all bundles before you start *any* bundles. The easiest way to do this is to accumulate the `Bundle` objects returned by `installBundle()` into a list, and then do a second loop over this list calling `Bundle.start()`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is the start level. I can't tell from what I see here what the start level of your bundles is, but that might be something for you to look into.

As to your question, the OSGI spec (version 4.3, that's what I have handy right now) describes this in section *4.4.2 Bundle State*. If your bundles haven't been started (either through start level or manually), they'll be in the installed state.

It might be helpful if you install the Felix gogo shell and inspect the bundle's start level and if all requirements are fulfilled. Hope that helps.

EDIT: Turns out I was wrong, removed this line: "I believe Felix will automatically attempt to resolve the bundles during installation time, but I have nothing to back this up right now."

Comment: No, Felix does not automatically resolve bundles when installed. Indeed it must not, that would be a violation of the specification and break a lot of stuff in OSGi.

Comment: Also, start level is irrelevant here because no bundles are started. Start level doesn't cause bundles to be magically started, it just controls the order in which the start instruction comes into effect.

Comment: You are right, Neil. Thanks for the correction. Regarding the start levels, wouldn't a bundle start level lower than the system level cause the framework to start the bundles in question?

Comment: No.. the OSGi Framework *never* automatically starts bundles, they always need to be started explicitly by calling `start()`. The only sort-of exception to this is that OSGi is persistent, so that if you shut down and restart, the bundles that were started previously will still be started in the new runtime.